# Object not found in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a couple of problem with the code below.  I am copying and pasting a chart from one file to another and then closing the file from which the chart came.  Everything works fine when I step througth the code in the debugger, but when I use the button on the sheet to fire the procedure it gives me an error: The object could not be found.

I am also getting flicker during the procedure even though I am using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`.

Can anyone help?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Windows("Overhead Display.xls").Activate
Sheets("CHART DISPLAY - FINISH").Activate
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartImage").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartImage").Delete

ChDir _
    "C:\...FILES"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\...BLACK.xls"
Sheets("RYG CHARTS").Visible = True
Sheets("RYG CHARTS").Activate
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="052100F"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
Windows("Overhead Display.xls").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
'Rename chart to delete later
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "ChartImage"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartImage").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ChartImage").Top = 100
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ChartImage").Width = 700
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ChartImage").Height = 375
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ChartImage").Left = 20


'ActiveWindow.Visible = False
Windows("Overhead Display.xls").Activate
Range("A1").Select
With ActiveWindow
    .DisplayGridlines = False
    .DisplayHeadings = False
    .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
    .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False
    .DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
End With



Windows("BMW F25 OUTERBELT BLACK.xls").Activate
Sheets("FILE SETUP").Activate
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="052100AF"
Range("J2").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Overhead Display.xls").Activate
Sheets("CHART DISPLAY - FINISH").Activate
Range("K2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Windows("BMW F25 OUTERBELT BLACK.xls").Activate
Range("J3").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Overhead Display.xls").Activate
Sheets("CHART DISPLAY - FINISH").Activate
Range("J3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Windows("BMW F25 OUTERBELT BLACK.xls").Activate
Range("D2").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Overhead Display.xls").Activate
Sheets("CHART DISPLAY - FINISH").Activate
Range("L4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Windows("BMW F25 OUTERBELT BLACK.xls").Activate
Range("D3").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Overhead Display.xls").Activate
Sheets("CHART DISPLAY - FINISH").Activate
Range("N3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Windows("BMW F25 OUTERBELT BLACK.xls").Activate
Range("H13").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Overhead Display.xls").Activate
Sheets("CHART DISPLAY - FINISH").Activate
Range("U11").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Windows("BMW F25 OUTERBELT BLACK.xls").Activate
Range("F13").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Overhead Display.xls").Activate
Sheets("CHART DISPLAY - FINISH").Activate
Range("U13").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Windows("BMW F25 OUTERBELT BLACK.xls").Activate
Range("G13").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Overhead Display.xls").Activate
Sheets("CHART DISPLAY - FINISH").Activate
Range("U15").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Windows("BMW F25 OUTERBELT BLACK.xls").Activate
Sheets("RAW DATA LIST").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A2") = ""
Windows("BMW F25 OUTERBELT BLACK.xls").Activate

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Windows("Overhead Display.xls").Activate
Sheets("CHART DISPLAY - FINISH").Activate
Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: What is the name of the workbook from where you are running this code?

Comment: I get the error at the line where I close the the file I get the chart from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UNTESTED**

Try this and tell me if you get any error?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wbThis As Workbook, WbOther As Workbook
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsThis = wbThis.Sheets("CHART DISPLAY - FINISH")

    wsThis.ChartObjects("ChartImage").Delete

    '~~> Change the path as required
    Set WbOther = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\...BLACK.xls")

    With WbOther.Sheets("RYG CHARTS")
        .Visible = True
        .Unprotect Password:="052100F"
        .ChartObjects("Chart 5").ChartArea.Copy
        wsThis.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End With

    wbThis.Activate
    'Rename chart to delete later
    ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "ChartImage"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartImage").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("ChartImage").Top = 100
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("ChartImage").Width = 700
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("ChartImage").Height = 375
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("ChartImage").Left = 20

    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayGridlines = False
        .DisplayHeadings = False
        .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
        .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False
        .DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
    End With

    With WbOther
        With .Sheets("FILE SETUP")
            '.Unprotect Password:="052100AF"
            wbThis.Range("K2").Value = .Range("J2").Value
            wbThis.Range("J3").Value = .Range("J3").Value
            wbThis.Range("L4").Value = .Range("D2").Value
            wbThis.Range("N3").Value = .Range("D3").Value
            wbThis.Range("U11").Value = .Range("H13").Value
            wbThis.Range("U13").Value = .Range("F13").Value
            wbThis.Range("U15").Value = .Range("G13").Value
        End With

        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method.  At line: .ChartObjects("Chart 5").ChartArea.Copy wsThis

Comment: One moment updating the above post

Comment: Ok do you have the sample files with you? I can test it and then update the above code?

Comment: The file it gets the image from is extremly large - 5mg+.  I can send you the smaller 'Display' file, but all I am copying is the Chart.  Why would it work in debug and not when fired from the sheet?

Comment: `Why would it work in debug and not when fired from the sheet?` That so what I want to find :) You can upload the files at wikisend.com if you want and shared the link here. I can then test it for you :)

Comment: I appreciate it, but I can't do that with sensitive data.

Comment: You can delete the data and just let the relevant charts/Sheets remain as it is?

Comment: I checked this as the answer.  I hope I have done this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the selects are one of the commands causing the flicker

instead of

```
Range("G13").Select
Selection.Copy
```

use

```
Range("G13").Copy
```

Comment: Still getting a lot of flicker.

Comment: activate creates flicker too. for example, all this
**ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy**
can be
**ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Copy**

Comment: OK, but I thought that using Application.ScreenUpdating = False simply does not update the screen?

Comment: I wish excel was that simple, but the commands **activate**, **select** and **selection** all cause flicker, even if you can't see the actual update